# TypeError: string indices must be integers error in BERT model

Tags: bert-language-model

[image]

[image]

I am trying to run a BERT model for a dataset of emotion annotated tweets. When running our command in cmd line to begin this process, this type error is thrown
Going to the line the error is shown, how could we fix this error in order for the model to work?

Our data files are two column csv files , the column on the left with the tweet and the column on the right with the annotated emotion in binary (0 for false 1 for positive)

How could we fix this?

Let me know!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The variable emb is a string. An index looks like this:

```
 >>> mystring = 'helloworld'
 >>> print mystring[0]
 >>> 'h'
```

The above example uses the 0 index of the string to refer to the first character. Strings can't have string indices (like dictionaries can). So this won't work:

```
>>> mystring = 'helloworld'
>>> print mystring['stringindex']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I suggest you try to print the data and check what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey, so Is there any way you think I could rewrite the rep = emb line?

Comment: Do you suggest I try to convert string EMB to float or int?

Comment: yes, try to print and see what emb is doing and type(emb). then based on that change this line rep=emb[ : ]